# Sum certain variables and delete duplicates after

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I have a data.frame which consists of 33 variables with 2.54 million observations. I created a simple data.frame from which I will explain my problem.

```
testdf
     borrower amount income
1        a   4000  30000
2        b   5000  20000
3        a   3000  30000

str(testdf)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ borrower: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 1
 $ amount  : num  4000 20000 3000
 $ income  : num  30000 20000 30000
```

What I want, is to sum the variable `amount` if the variable `borrower` is the same. But this must not be done for the variable `income`. And after this, the duplicate must be deleted. So in this case, row 3 must be deleted. The new df has to look like this:

```
testdf
     borrower  amount  income
     a          7000    30000
     b          5000    20000
```

It is also possible that a value in variable `borrower` (a for instance) occurs 8 times. In that matter, I want to sum the 8 `amounts`s but again, not the `income`. And delete 7 rows with a.

Comment: Does `income` remain same for the `borrower` across the 8 rows? If not, how are you selecting the value for `income` in your resultant dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with `plyr`:

```
testdf <- data.frame(borrower = c("a", "b", "a"),
                     amount = c(4000, 5000, 3000),
                     income = c(30000, 20000, 30000))


library(plyr)
ddply(testdf, .(borrower), summarise, amount = sum(amount), income = income[1])

#   borrower amount income
# 1        a   7000  30000
# 2        b   5000  20000
```